# boto3 EC2 client for each sub account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use the python `boto3` AWS SDK to loop through sub accounts to determine in-use CIDR ranges for VPCs.  From the root account I can see all the sub accounts using the following:

```
organizations = boto3.client('organizations')
response = organizations.list_accounts_for_parent(
    ParentId='FOO'
)
```

I would then like to use the EC2 -> `describe_vpcs` to identify in-use CIDR ranges.  Can someone give me some advice on connecting these two pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would need to **assume a role** in each sub-account. This will then provide temporary credentials that can be used to make API calls in the sub-account.

From [Accessing and Administering the Member Accounts in Your Organization - AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html):

> When you create an account in your organization, AWS Organizations automatically creates a root user and an IAM role for the account. ... If you create an account in your organization, you can **access the account by using the preconfigured role** that exists in all new accounts that are created this way.
>
> ...
>
> When you create a member account using the AWS Organizations console, AWS Organizations automatically creates an **IAM role** in the account. This role has full administrative permissions in the member account. The role is also configured to **grant that access to the organization's master account**.